# Split number by decimal

Tags: r

I'm trying to split a number with a decimal into 2 separate numbers (characters work as well).

```
a <- c(1241.3233, 5632.2344, 1313,8643)
```

I would like to return this

```
col1    col2
1241    3233
5632    2344
1313    8643
```

I've tried

```
strsplit(as.character(a), ".")
```

and

```
stringr::str_split(a,".")
```

with no success.

Comment: `strsplit(as.character(1241.3233),"\\.")`

Comment: You might want to make your decimal place consistent. Either "." or ","

Comment: UpV for d.b.but ericbrownaustin should read ?regex carefully so he understands why "." is going to match any character. There must be 10 or 20 similar questions on SO.

Comment: You can use `csplit` from `splitstackshape` , `cSplit(data.frame(a), "a", ".")`

Comment: Decimal? A decimal is a digit in the range 0-9. Do you mean 'decimal *point*'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two points:

1) Coerce number to string using `as.character`

2) Escape the period using `\\`

```
a = c(1241.3233, 5632.2344, 1313.8643)
do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(a),"\\."))
#     [,1]   [,2]  
#[1,] "1241" "3233"
#[2,] "5632" "2344"
#[3,] "1313" "8643"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on a data frame, and your desired output is going to be a data frame. The `separate` function from `tidyr` could be useful. Here is an example.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame
dt <- data.frame(a = c(1241.3233, 5632.2344, 1313.8643))

# Separate the column a into col1 and col2
dt2 <- dt %>%
  separate(a, into = c("col1", "col2"))
```